# electron-builder packaged executable cannot find a user-written file saying no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, path, electron, electron-builder, asar

The file has no problem being found from the unpackaged version booted with "electron . ".

Ex: the file is referenced in code as something like: "const some_package = require('./sample_folder/sample_file.js' ". (Obviously not the actual file names, but if somehow underscores or something is a problem, please let me know)

I've tried disabling asar, using app.getpath with the path module, putting the file path in asarUnpack, and slightly varying the file path special characters, but nothing seems to work.